# How do I create a Graphical Timeline using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, timeline

I am trying to create a timeline as per the screenshot attached. Can anybody give me pointers how to go about creating this kind of component using javascript/jquery?

Note: Kindly ignore the dates mismatch!
[image: Timeline Screenshot]
Thanks!

Comment: Try this http://timeline.knightlab.com/

Comment: Hi K K, I tried but this is not what I am looking for, I don't want the slide show on upper portion. Instead I need to have a horizontal slider below to navigate across timeline.

Comment: Curious what you ended up doing – found anything? Came across this in my search – which seems to meet most requirements: http://almende.github.io/chap-links-library/timeline.html

Answer (score 0):

Timelinejs plugin will be helpful:

https://github.com/NUKnightLab/TimelineJS